# Calculating E^2[σ^2] where σ is a GARCH(1,1) Proces

Tags: options, option-pricing, volatility, garch, expected-value

Given that α = 0,113079 β = 0,873884 ω = 0,0000081

I need to calculate a call price using garch volatility; I also calculated the kurtosis = 235:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265442526_A_Black-Scholes_model_with_GARCH_volatility

[image]

Comment: Wouldn’t that simply be $(E(\sigma_t^2))^2$?

Comment: Cross posted (and answered) at Cross Validated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/524010).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s crossposted and answered elsewhere.